# openvc/cv_bridge encoding

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which encoding is most appropriate for using cv_bridge to convert cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3d> matrices into ros images?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11275/openvc/cv_bridge-encoding/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-09-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_64FC3`. In the OpenCV naming scheme, this is 64-bit floating point (64F, aka double) with 3 channels (C3).

The full list of encodings is defined in `sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h` and viewable [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1image__encodings.html). We define some named encodings (like `RGB8`) that specify the color semantics as well as data type and number of channels. The `TYPE_*` encodings support arbitrary data.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Median](https://answers.ros.org/users/4366/median/) on 2013-03-11**:
No matter what enconding type I use, I always get the same message: [ERROR] [1363015855.837613897]: cv_bridge exception: Unrecognized image encoding []. Can you please help me?